# Post formats are not working on the post page

Tags: post, post-format

Im working on a blog website. I have different post formats in the theme Im useing. Yesterday I add some codes in to style.php and one of them kind of working.

For example I add this code ;

.link .post_img { background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center center, rgb(22, 187, 231) 0%, rgb(15, 25, 94) 100%) }

I have about 4 post in ''link'' post format.

The code I added work only on 1 of them. When I click source code on the post page the code works. I see this . but others post are showing me this . When I write this post they all are same format as link.

I want to give different bg color to attached post_img for diffirent post_formats.

I dont understant why the code I add works only on one of the posts...

Can anybody help me out about this problem...

Answer (score 0):

***This is from functions.php I guess there is something wrong, maybe ???***

add_filter( 'post_class', 'metro_creativex_post_class' );

function metro_creativex_post_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;

```
if (is_single( $post->ID )) :
    $class[] = 'post';
else :
    $format = get_post_format( $post->ID );
    if ($format == 'aside') :
        $class[] = 'bg-design';
    elseif (($format == 'audio') || ($format == 'video')) :
        $class[] = 'bg-wordpress';
    elseif (($format == 'gallery') || ($format == 'image')) :
        $class[] = 'bg-responsive';
    elseif (($format == 'link') || ($format == 'quote') || ($format == 'status')) :
        $class[] = 'bg-web';
    else :
        $class[] = 'bg-stuff';
    endif;
endif;

return $class;
```

}